# how to create unique_ptr from inherited parent class

Tags: c++, inheritance, unique-ptr

Is there a way to create a `unique_ptr` from one of the inherited classes?

I need to be able to "register" `MouseListeners` with a manager but I cannot figure out how to create the `unique_ptr` of the inherited `MouseListener`.

The error is that it cannot find a conversion from `Window *` to `MouseListener`. I have tried a `static_cast` but that produces other errors. I have also tried passing in a `raw pointer` to the `addMouseListener` which did work but errored when you close the program as I think it did not create the appropriate memory which causes the `delete` to fail.

Also using `std::move()` transfers ownership which causes the listener to not fire the event.

```
// Window.h
class Window : public MouseManager, public MouseListener {
public:
    Window::Window(std::string title, int32_t width, int32_t height) {
        ...
        this->addMouseListener(std::make_unique<MouseListener>(this)); // ERROR
    }
};

// MouseManager.h
void MouseManager::addMouseListener(std::unique_ptr<MouseListener> listener) {
    m_listeners.emplace_back(listener);
}

// MouseListener.h

MouseListener() = default;

virtual ~MouseListener() = default;
MouseListener(const MouseListener& listener) = default;
MouseListener(MouseListener&& listener) noexcept ;
MouseListener& operator=(const MouseListener& listener) = delete;
MouseListener& operator=(MouseListener&& listener) = delete;
```

Error output

```
In file included from /Users/Programmer/CLionProjects/StormEngine/Engine/Window/Window.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/Programmer/CLionProjects/StormEngine/Engine/Window/Window.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:3141:32: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'MouseListener'
    return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...));
                               ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Programmer/CLionProjects/StormEngine/Engine/Window/Window.cpp:17:33: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::make_unique<MouseListener, Window *>' requested here
    this->addMouseListener(std::make_unique<MouseListener>(this));
                                ^
/Users/Programmer/CLionProjects/StormEngine/Engine/Window/../Events/Listeners/MouseListener.h:19:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Window *' to 'const MouseListener' for 1st argument; dereference the argument with *
    MouseListener(const MouseListener& listener) = default;
    ^
/Users/Programmer/CLionProjects/StormEngine/Engine/Window/../Events/Listeners/MouseListener.h:20:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Window *' to 'MouseListener' for 1st argument; dereference the argument with *
    MouseListener(MouseListener&& listener) noexcept ;
    ^
/Users/Programmer/CLionProjects/StormEngine/Engine/Window/../Events/Listeners/MouseListener.h:16:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
    MouseListener() = default;
    ^
```

Update:

de-referencing `this` adds a new problem where to add the variable `listener` you have to `std::move()` which causes the change of ownership which as stated above causes the events not to fire.

Comment: 1. Did you read the error message? 2. Create a [mcve].

Comment: I specified what the error was with this implementation. "it cannot find a conversion from `Window*` to `MouseListener`. I will post the error log just for extra clarity in case people miss it.

Comment: What are the constructors for `MouseListener`?

Comment: all three are shown in the error log. I can add this into the question if needed.

Comment: @Matthew You will need to add the definitions of all the types. But remove the use of types that are not needed to demonstrate the problem. And remove the parts of the definitions as well, if they aren't needed. In other words, create a [mcve].

Comment: @user2079303 yes you are certainly correct I have made the necessary additions.

Comment: The class MouseListener has no constructor that takes a MouseListener-pointer (here this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> std::make_unique<MouseListener>(this)
> ```

This allocates a new `MouseListener` instance, with `this` as an argument to the constructor. As the error message explains, there is no constructor `MouseListener:MouseListener(Window*)` or any other constructor with a parameter to which `Window*` could be implicitly converted.

You probably didn't intend to create a new `MouseListener` instance, but instead want a unique pointer to `this`. You can create a `unique_ptr` to `this` using the constructor `explicit unique_ptr(pointer p)`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Window>(this)
```

This pointer can be passed to `MouseManager::addMouseListener`. Note that while the conversion from a deriver unique pointer is implicit, a base unique pointer cannot be directly constructed from a bare derived pointer, because the constructor is explicit.

---

Note that creating a unique pointer to `this` is probably a dubious idea. It limits the creation of `Window` objects to using `new`, and apparently (from the perspective of the code that allocates) leaking the pointer. No other code can own any windows (unless moved from the container where it was initially stored), and you can never have automatic instances.

Comment: so if I understand you correctly inheriting `Window` from `MouseListener` is fine but use something like a global `MouseManager`?

Comment: Inheriting `Window` from `MouseListener` violates single responsibility principle. Using composition is probably a less smelly design.

Comment: Okay after reading up on composition it looks like you are saying that it is a good idea to have a variable `MouseListener` inside the `Window` class?

Answer (score 1):

make unique makes an object of that type and returns a pointer to it.

It does not wrap a pre existing pointer to an object into a unique ptr.

Your `addMouseListener(std::unique_ptr<MouseListener>)` function *takes ownership* of the listener.  Passing a preexiting object is not generally a good idea here.

Probably `Window` should not inherit from `MouseListener` but instead create a `MouseListener` that in turn has a pointer to the `Window` and somehow does lifetime management to ensure the `Window` alive stays around, or us disconnected when the `Window` dies.

The `MouseListener` should *relay* messages to the window, not *be* the window.